# SAN GPFS for db2 hadr share archive log

Tags: database, historical-unix, db2, ibm-unix-system-services

Did any one use SAN GPFS for db2 hadr shared archive log. Or any other solution for shared archive log between 2 different Sites. Primary site has 2 databasea and DR site has 2 AUX databases